# How can loading text of error message dynamically is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation plugin for form validation on my *.aspx web-page.
I have a question:

Can i load the text of an error message dynamically or get it from a DOM-element 
( by selector ) and place it in another element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood you correctly:

One simple (some might say "hacky") way of doing this is: to write out your error messages as values in hidden inputs, and load them from there as needed.

You have to provide some code so we can get the context of what you are trying to do.